# Change country of intlTelInput from another select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown, intl-tel-input

I want to change the country selected in the intl-Tel-Input based on another select list. e.g. if Malaysia is selected in the country select list, the intl-Tel-Input should be changed to malaysia and should display its flag and code. similary if the country is changed to United States, the intl-Tel-Input should change accordingly.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: I am facing the same issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61369235/reactjs-intltelinput-flag-doesnt-change-when-the-preferredcountries-attribute-v

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create js object "kind of json format" containing all the country code with there specific names, and dynamically try to alter the input placeholder once the country selected matches using javascript

Answer (score 0):

if you are using React, here is the solution

```
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        updated:true
    }
}
```

To keep tracking if country is being changed.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(this.props.selectedCountry !== nextProps.selectedCountry){
        this.setState({
            updated:false
        })
    }
}
```

tells you its going to change now

```
componentDidUpdate(nextProps){
    if(this.props.selectedCountry !== nextProps.selectedCountry){
        this.setState({
            updated:true
        })
    }
}
```

Changed now.

```
render(){
    const { selectedCountry } = this.props;
    var countryCode = 'us'
    if(selectedCountry)
        countryCode = selectedCountry.toLowerCase()

    var field = <Field
         className="ibm-fullwidth urx-country"
         name="phone" 
         onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
         component={this.renderPhoneInput} 
         defaultCountry={countryCode}
        />

    return (
        <span>
        {this.state.updated &&
            <span>{field}</span>
        }
        </span>
    )
}
```

Basically its is re-rendering on country change.

Comment: This made no change in my case. I am facing the same issue here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61369235/reactjs-intltelinput-flag-doesnt-change-when-the-preferredcountries-attribute-v